# How to open xlsx file in LibreOffice on Ubuntu?

Tags: python

I want to open a file in LibreOffice Calc on Ubuntu after working on it through Python.

How would I go about this?

I tried:

```
import subprocess

subprocess.call("explorer path-to-file")

# got error that the path doesn't exist

subprocess.call("calc path-to-file")

# Calc is not executable type error
```

Comment: "got error that the path doesn't exist" - then you should provide a path that does exist. Speaking about opening Calc: https://help.libreoffice.org/Common/Starting_the_Software_With_Parameters

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the `xdg-open` tool (if you have it) to use the default tool for the file type, or if you really want to always use Libreoffice, the executable for it is `libreoffice`.

```py
os.system("xdg-open path-to-file")
os.system("libreoffice path-to-file")
```

(and as always when using `os.system()`, make sure `path-to-file` comes from a trusted source.)